Is it possible to emulate a directory/partition in C++ on Windows
I'm wondering if it's possible to emulate a partition or, preferably, a directory, without a need to develop a filesystem driver. And this partition is visible to Windows and other applications, works like a regular directory or partition, but I/O is under my app's control - I override read/write/open/close/list functions for that particular directory so I can supply information to the OS of how many files and directories inside the directory, their sizes, filenames and etc.
Thank you in advance

You can create a custom Shell Namespace Extension to display whatever items you want in Windows Explorer. They won't be part of the file system, though, so not accessible using regular file paths, but other apps can interact with them using Shell interfaces (IShellFolder, IShellItem, etc). If you want the items to show on the filesystem, then you need a custom filesystem driver

In addition to a Shell Namespace Extension (which is limited to Shell operations), you can also make use of the Windows Projected File System (ProjFS). It allows for a user-mode "provider" to emulate a file system. I believe this was introduced in preparation for VFS for Git support.

Seems like ProjFS is exactly what I need, thank you!

The main options are:

real-time drive emulation, where all filesystem requests go to your code
synchronization of data using CfAPI
a shell namespace extension

All these options have their pros and cons. Of course, a driver-based option (1) is the most powerful, unless installing a driver is a no-go. Synchronization can be a viable option if you are ok with the fact that a copy of your data is stored locally (this can be undesired if you deal with security and/or data protection). A shell namespace is generally a read-only view to the data, in the meaning that applications have a hard time with saving files into a namespace extension folder (this is virtually impossible unless an application is crafted specifically for this option).
Our company, Callback Technologies, offers several library products that can meet different aspects (or all) of your demands. Most products include a pre-built driver or two, and CBFS Shell, used to create shell extensions, is a pure user-mode solution.
